# C Array Memory Error?(Beginner)

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

When I try to print all the values in the array(which should be zero?), it starts printing 0's but at the end prints wonky numbers:

"(printing zeros)...0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1810432,0,1809600,0,1809600,0,0,0,5,0,3907584..."

When I extend the array, only at the end do the numbers start to mess up. Is this a memory limitation or something? Very confused, would greatly appreciate if anyone could help a newbie out.

Done in CS50IDE, not sure if that changes anything

```
int main()
{
  int counter [100000];
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    printf("%i,", counter[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Array not initialised?

Comment: Variables with automatic storage duration, (locals), are uninitialized by default.

Comment: Note that the array is allocated on the stack, but the stack has a finite and relatively small size (typically 8 MiB on Unix-like systems and I believe 1 MiB on WIndows-like systems).  If you make the array much bigger, it won't fit on the stack.  If the array was defined at file scope, it would be default initialized to zero — but local (automatic) variables are not initialized like that.  You could also use dynamic memory allocation — but `malloc()` would not initialize the data, while `calloc()` would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto` variables (variables declared within a block without the `static` keyword) are not initialized to any particular value when they are created; their value is *indeterminate*.  You can't rely on that value being 0 or anything else.

`static` variables (declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword) are initialized to 0 or `NULL`, depending on type.

You can initialize all of the elements of the array to 0 by doing

```
int counter [100000] = {{0}};
```

If there are fewer elements in the initializer than there are elements in the array, then the extra elements are initialized *as though* they were `static` - 0 or `NULL`.  So the first element is being *explicitly* initialized to 0, and the remaining 99999 elements are *implicitly* initialized to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your array isn't initialized. You simply declare it but never actually set it. In C (and C++, Objective-C) you need to manually set a starting value. Unlike Python, Java, JavaScript or C# this isn't done for you...

> which should be zero?

The above assertion is incorrect.

Comment: "you need to manually set a starting value" that's not true for all types of storage.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because you reserved 100000*4 = 400000 bytes of memory but didn't write anything to it (didn't initialize it).

So therefore, garbage is printed if you access a memory location which hasn't been written to yet. The reason why 0's aren't printed is because we want optimization and don't want the compiler wasting time in writing to 100000 integer addresses and also the best practices expect a developer to never access a memory place that he has never written to or allocated yet. If you try printing:

```
printf("%d\n", counter[100000]);
```

This would also print a garbage value, but you didn't allocate that did you? It's because C/C++ don't restrict or raise errors when you try to do such operation unlike Java.

Try it yourself

```
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    counter[i] = i;
    printf("%d\n", counter[i]);
}
```

Now only numbers from 1,2,3....99999 will be printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array in C, it does not set the elements to zero by default. Instead, it will be filled with whatever data last occupied that location in memory, which could be anything.

The fact that the first portion of the array contained zeros is just a coincidence.

This beginning state of an array is referred to as an "uninitialized" array, as you have not provided any initial values for the array. Before you can use the array, it should be "initialized", meaning that you specify a default value for each position.